# How to use Numpy as Default for Code Generation In Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, code-generation

I'm digging into SymPy's code generation capabilities and am struggling with a few basic things. Ironically, of all the languages that SymPy supports for code generation, the documentation for python code generation seems to be the most minimal/lacking. I would like to use `numpy as np` as the default for all math functions in the code conversion but am struggling. Looking at the source code (since it is not documented), it looks like you can input a `settings` dict that has a `user_functions` field which maps SymPy functions to custom functions. I have a basic example below:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing.pycode import PythonCodePrinter

class MyPrinter(PythonCodePrinter):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__({'user_functions':{'cos':'np.cos', 'sin':'np.sin', 'sqrt':'np.sqrt'}})
    
x = sp.symbols('x')
expr = sp.sqrt(x) + sp.cos(x)
mpr = MyPrinter()
mpr.doprint(expr)
```

This produces the following output:
`'math.sqrt(x) + np.cos(x)'`

You can see that the mapping worked correctly for `cos` but not for `sqrt`.

1. Why am I getting this behavior?
2. Is there a better way to do this than to manually specify numpy funcs for every function I want to use?

Comment: Have you considered using `sympy.printing.numpy.NumPyPrinter` instead?

Comment: That class will output `'numpy.sqrt(x) + numpy.cos(x)'` for your expression. The docstring for `NumPyPrinter.__init__` says, _"`settings` is passed to CodePrinter.__init__()
        `module` specifies the array module to use, currently 'NumPy', 'CuPy'
        or 'JAX'."_. However it doesn't take a `module` argument, and `NumPyPrinter._module` is hardcoded to `numpy` in the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/24792d5f4fbf8fe4365101e53b735c6c1f140e0f/sympy/printing/numpy.py#L41).

Comment: Also the module `numpy` is [hardcoded in the lines](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/24792d5f4fbf8fe4365101e53b735c6c1f140e0f/sympy/printing/numpy.py#L32) that are then used to create `_known_functions_numpy` and `_known_constants_numpy`. Might be easiest to extend that class and [redefine `_kf` and `_kc`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/24792d5f4fbf8fe4365101e53b735c6c1f140e0f/sympy/printing/numpy.py#L42) to use `self._module`

Comment: Based on SO problems with `sympy.lambdify` don't try to pass `sympy` symbols and expressions to `numpy` functions.  And be wary of trying to construct numpy arrays from sympy structures.  The `lambdify' translation is pretty shallow, without much understanding of numpy syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a `sympy.printing.numpy.NumPyPrinter` class that uses `numpy` functions instead of `math` functions. The docstring for its `__init__` says:

> `module` specifies the array module to use, currently 'NumPy', 'CuPy' or 'JAX'."

but the method doesn't take a `module` argument. Moreover, the name of the module is hardcoded as `numpy` in the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/24792d5f4fbf8fe4365101e53b735c6c1f140e0f/sympy/printing/numpy.py#L41). Also, the lines that define the known functions and constants in the numpy module use a hardcoded `'numpy.'` to create the values for the `_kc` and `_kf` dictionaries, although there exist separate classes [`CuPyPrinter`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/24792d5f4fbf8fe4365101e53b735c6c1f140e0f/sympy/printing/numpy.py#L449) and [`JAXPrinter`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/24792d5f4fbf8fe4365101e53b735c6c1f140e0f/sympy/printing/numpy.py#L472) that define their own `_module`, `_kf`, and `_kc` variables

IMO the simplest way would be to extend the `NumPyPrinter` class so that it takes a `module` argument and uses it to create its `_kf` and `_kc` dictionaries, which are then used by the original `__init__` to create the `known_functions` and `known_constants` dictionaries:

```
import sympy.printing.numpy as spn

class NumPyPrinter(spn.NumPyPrinter):
    def __init__(self, settings=None, module='numpy'):
        self._module = module
        m = module + "."
        self._kf = {k: m + v for k, v in spn._known_functions_numpy.items()}
        self._kc = {k: m + v for k, v in spn._known_constants_numpy.items()}
        
        super().__init__(settings=settings)
```

Now, using this printer to print your expression gives the expected output: `np.sqrt(x) + np.cos(x)`

```
x = sp.symbols('x')
expr = sp.sqrt(x) + sp.cos(x)

npr = NumPyPrinter(module='np')
print(npr.doprint(expr))
```